# two way difference in sending cookies with requests by restAssured?

Tags: java, rest-assured

as far as i know there is two ways to work with RestAssured, long and short one.

at the short way to send request with cookie you just use

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://example.com/";
```

than for the cookie

```
given().cookie(“cookiname", “cookie value").when().get(“URL").then().statusCode(200);
```

and than you can use cookie builder if needed

but at the long way with:

```
Response response = httpRequest.get("/something");
```

how you send the cookie?
i saw something like:

```
RestAssured.requestSpecification = new RequestSpecBuilder().addCookie("my cookie","mycookievalue").build();
```

but still i didn't understand it and didn't saw an request with that, can you explain me these please?